# Texts with same color code is different when loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a webshop with green as a primary color.
Everything works great, but I noticed that text within a ajax loaded div is brighter then it should be. The regular loaded text is noticeably less bright but both texts have the exact same color code.

I don't think I can reproduce it here without posting the entire CSS and HTML file, but here is a HTML snippet of text on normal page load:

```
<div class="primary-product-text vis-product-name">Knie-insteekkoppeling, kunststof zwart, M6</div>
```

And a snippet from the dynamically loaded content:

```
<span class="primary-product-text">Knie insteekkoppeling, kunststof zwart, M6</span>
```

CSS:

```
.primary-product-text {
    color: #01a85e;
}

.vis-product-name {
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
}
```

Link: https://www.technicomponents.nl/nl/p/pneumatiek/insteekkoppelingen/knie-koppelingen/
The shown products have a green color. If you click on the cart icon next to a product or search for "knie" you'll see that the same colorcode produces a brighter green color.

Comment: inspect the element with browser console and check if span or div elements has particular css

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue

Comment: Sfili_81 I did that, can't find anything odd

Comment: Adesh Kumar, View the webpage if you haven't, since I don't know where the problem is I can't make a reproducable snippet here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it was because of CSS animations that caused some text rendering issues. I had several CSS animations like transform and scale on the container and individual divs.

The solution was to add the following CSS code to the main container class:

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 1):

It might be browser rendering.
I noticed that even though the CSS seems the same, the pixels are not generated the same. This could be related to the font being relatively thin and `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` being turned on.

While looking at it, I also realized that the text in the popup is different, please my best guess would be to use the exact same text. (the minus between `Knie` and `insteekkoppeling`)

[image]
(the first one is the web-page, the second one from the popup)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, Nederlands toevallig?
Right now I'm looking on Mac and I don't get the problem, even on Chrome on Mac.
Will make a video/screenshot tomorrow to show you what happens.

Comment: Strange thing is, I just get the html content with jquery .get and add the html to a div, so no iframe or other stuff like that, just straight into the dom. I'll try adding the aliasing to the loaded text, maybe that only the regular loaded content gets anti-aliased and the ajax content not. Although I never had any problems with that.

Comment: My screenshots were made on a mac, in Chrome (77.0.3865.120), on an extra non-retina monitor. Both have `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` already set. (as well as all the other related CSS seems to be the same).

Comment: I think I know what triggers it, not why it does that.
If i load the loaded html straight into a div on the page that was loaded on pageload it works. As soon as I load the modal box the colors shift. If i remove position:fixed it will show the right color.
ALSO: it only appears to occur on Windows. Both on Mac and Android phone with Chrome the problem doesn't exist.